# Undefined offset for $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I have been trying to create a very simple shopping cart and I'm having a problem with my `$_SESSION` array. This is for a school project and I'm trying to make it as simple as possible.

The error I'm getting is:

> Notice: Undefined index: cart in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\menu.php on
>      line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\menu.php    on
>      line 31

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $product_id = $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
    print_r($_SESSION);
    print "<br>";
    print_r($_GET);
}
```

Once I've added more than one item to a particular `product_id`, the error goes away. This is the way the tutorial I read explained to add items to the cart. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can check `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]` if it is set, then increment it, and why are you incrementing the product id?

Comment: Did you remember to call `session_start()` at the top of this script? You must call it on _every_ script which reads or writes `$_SESSION`

Comment: @kevinabelita incrementing an array element identified by a product id is a fine way to keep track of the quantities of different items in a cart.

Comment: Kevin, $product_id is a reference to a product, so any time another item of the same type is added it increases the quantity.

Comment: I did remember to call session_start() as well. Prior to adding anything to the cart, the $_SESSION['cart'] will not exist. I thought it was created when you assign a value to it. This has worked in other situations in another part of this same project I'm working on.

Comment: You may want to `var_dump($_SESSION)` to make sure your session array is being built the way you want it to, and to make sure you don't have typos in the array keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like $_SESSION['cart'] does not yet exist.  Since it's going to be an array, instantiate it first with:

```
if(!array_key_exists('cart', $_SESSION)) $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
```

Since you have not yet assigned anything to `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]`, you'll get this type of error when trying to increment it.  You may want to try:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = (array_key_exists($product_id, $_SESSION['cart'])) ? $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] +1 : 1;
```

or as an `if` statement:

```
if(array_key_exists($product_id, $_SESSION['cart'])) $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
else $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 1;
```

Comment: Using this method I was able to fix it. Thanks SuperJer

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;` you are actually doing:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] + 1;
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ generates warning if they keys do not exist yet
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assigns without problems if they keys do not exist yet
```

The assignment with newly created keys is not the problem, the warning is generated by php trying to get the actual value of `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]`.

To solve this you should properly initialize the variable:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])
                                    ? $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++ 
                                    : 1;
```

Comment: I kinda follow the logic here, but I"m too much of a novice to be fluent in that short hand style using ? and :. I would have to dig through the documentation again to understand that fully. Thanks for the advice though jeroen.

Comment: The shorthand is fairly simple once you understand it.  If you look up 'ternary' or 'php ternary', you'll figure it out quickly.  Ternaries are almost universally supported.